# Error code -11?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I do sometimes get the error code -11 while building my ros package. I am using groovy.
Has someone found a list describing error codes? That would help debugging.

Thanks in advance,

Daniel

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/153411/error-code--11-?/) by [dneuhold](https://answers.ros.org/users/5295/dneuhold/) on ROS Answers with karma: 205 on 2014-04-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-04-15**:
Do you get that while building or executing? If it's really during the build, which step/program causes this? What output is there? 11 is usually a segfault. This seems unlikely to be caused by a build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

-11 could be python segfaulting. It would be good if you updated your question with a precise description of how this error occurs reproducably.

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-04-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1